# PowerShell: Start service and dependent services

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was looking up how to start a service and it's dependent services, and I was reading [this site](http://4sysops.com/archives/managing-services-the-powershell-way-part-3/).

It has an example:

```
get-service lanmanserver | Foreach { start-service $_.name -passthru; start-service $_.DependentServices -passthru}
```

However, when I run the above cmdlet, I get the error:

```
Start-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController'.
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?
Also, I've been using a different way to start a service and it's dependencies:

```
get-service lanmanserver | select -expand DependentServices | start-service
```

Any feedback on the workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `start-service $_.DependentServices` returns a collection of services and you're passing it to `Start-Service` as an argument for the `Name` parameter (default parameterset's 0th position parameter).  Try this instead:

```
... Start-Service -InputObject $_.DependentServices -passthru ...
```

Comment: Hey Keith, I have a follow-up question.
When I use -InputObject, it will give me an error message if no dependent service exists. Is there a way to get around this? I want to use this cmdlet for a variety of services. Some of these services may or may not have dependent services.

Comment: Try this, `$_.DependentServices | Start-Service -PassThru`